# Wordpress Widgets Not displaying on my Magento site

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

I'm using fishpig plugin to intergrate my blog with magento. However for some reason my wordpress widgets aren't displaying at all. I tried following this link but nothing changed anyone got an ideas?

http://fishpig.co.uk/wordpress-integration/docs/widgets.html

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Are there any error messages/output at all?

Comment: Shows no errors messages and only shows the blog post with no widgets in the left sidebar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok we just completely reinstalled wordpress and fishpig all seems to be working properly. Possibly due to a previous version of fishpig being removed poorly.